# No bootable device - insert boot disk and press any key after Boot Camp

Tags: mac, windows, bootcamp

When I tried to install Windows on my iMac I must have have formatted the wrong disk. Now when start I get no bootable device - insert boot disk and press any key. Any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried installing Windows again with the DVD ? (Boot on the DVD w/ option key at the chime)

Comment: Just to clarify, your Mac doesn't boot at all, not even OS X?